# Tablesorter - Sorting pair of tables with same order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I'm using `Tablesorter` and [`ZURB Responsive Table`](http://zurb.com/playground/playground/responsive-tables/index.html). The responsive table will break the tables into two: One to store sticky column (won't move) and the second one will be horizontally scrollable.

The problem is: since it is separate table, **sorting one of them won't sort the other**.

**Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DarcFiddle/Mff8y/)**. If you click the `<th>` on the right-side, it will only short the right-table and vice versa.

Any easy solution for this? Or must I write custom-made `tablesorter`?

**Notes**: Try minimizing the JSFiddle Result window to see the responsive table